# When debugging in pycharm, memory will continue to increase with logging

Tags: python, pycharm

Debugging runs the following code:

```
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger()
while True:
    logger.info('test')
```

In the Task Manager I can see that memory continues to increase.

But it won't happen when I run it directly.

I wonder how to avoid it, because I need long time logging when I debug.

Comment: What is your question? Why this is happening? If you can prevent it? Is it a problem? Welcome to Stackoverflow btw (;

Comment: @Bernhard Thank you for your reminder ~ I have modified the description.

Comment: Well, first you have 'Show memory indicator' under appearance in Settings to track in live the memory status.
Second, you can configure the initial and maximum head sizes and the file sizes that Pycharm can open - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tuning-the-ide.html

Comment: @mta194 When the Pycharm's memory reaches its maximum value, the code will not continue to run.